# How can I consolidate this code to avoid multiple #temp table writes?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Although this code is working, it isn't very efficient--making heavy use of temp tables, which I'd rather consolidate.  The create sumtest table and the insert statements that write to it are included for anyone interested in working with the sample data.

```
        CREATE TABLE SumTest(
            POSDate datetime NULL,
            debit money NULL,
            credit money NULL,
            RollingBalance money NULL,
            expires datetime NULL,
            ExpiringDebitBalance_2013 money,
            ExpiringDebitBalance_2014 money
        );

        -- mimic actual sales transactions

        insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Jan  5 2013 12:00AM','670.00','22.00','Dec 31 2014 12:00AM');
        insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Jan  6 2013 12:00AM','821.00','0.00','Dec 31 2014 12:00AM');
        insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Mar  8 2013 12:00AM','62.00','700.00','Dec 31 2014 12:00AM');
        insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Mar 11 2013 12:00AM','78.00','29.00','Dec 31 2014 12:00AM');
        insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Mar 11 2013 12:00AM','900.00','87.00','Dec 31 2014 12:00AM');
        insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Apr 16 2013 12:00AM','0.00','440.00',NULL);
        insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Aug 18 2013 12:00AM','0.00','50.00',NULL);
        insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Aug 19 2013 12:00AM','470.00','200.00','Dec 31 2014 12:00AM');
        insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Dec 31 2012 12:00AM','1000.00','200.00','Dec 31 2013 12:00AM');
        insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Dec 22 2013 12:00AM','200.00','0.00','Dec 31 2014 12:00AM');
        insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Dec 20 2013 12:00AM','500.00','0.00','Dec 31 2014 12:00AM');
        insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Nov 10 2012 12:00AM','200.00','0.00','Dec 31 2013 12:00AM');
        insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Nov 11 2012 12:00AM','150.00','0.00','Dec 31 2013 12:00AM');
        insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Nov 15 2012 12:00AM','0.00','100.00',NULL);

      -- // ---------- REAL CODE BEGINS -------------------------- // --

        create table #work
        (   
            POSYear int NULL,
            POSMonth int NULL,
            debit money NULL,
            credit money NULL,
            RollingBalance money NULL,
            expires datetime
        )

        -- start with ditching the time

        insert into #work
            (POSYear,POSMonth,debit,credit,expires)
        select datepart(Year, POSDate) as POSYear
                ,datepart(Month, POSDate) as POSMonth
                ,debit
                ,credit
                ,expires
        from sumtest



        -- dump an ordered set by year,month with a rolling balance of all points/redemptions

        ;with distilled as
            (select POSYear,
                    POSMonth,
                    TotalDebit = sum(debit),
                    TotalCredit = sum(credit),
                    expires
            from #work
            group by POSYear,POSMonth,expires
            )

        select POSYear,
                POSMonth,
                TotalDebit,
                TotalCredit,
                RollingBalance =  sum(totaldebit + (totalcredit)*-1) over ( order by POSYear, POSMonth),
                expires
        into #work2
        from distilled
        order by POSYear,POSMonth,TotalDebit,TotalCredit



        -- filter out credits lines that dont have an expiration date
                    -- Note: I would rather not do this--if there is a better way
                    --       to sum up by yyyy,mm here to consolidate to 
                    --       single rows please advise. 

        select x.POSYear,
                x.POSMonth,
                sum(x.TotalDebit) as TotalDebit,
                sum(x.TotalCredit) as TotalCredit,
                x.RollingBalance,
                EXPYear = datepart(Year, y.expires),
                EXPMonth = datepart(Month, y.expires)
        into #work3
        from #work2 x
            inner join #work2 y on x.posyear = y.posyear
                            and x.posmonth = y.posmonth
        where y.expires is not null
        group by x.posyear,x.posmonth,x.rollingbalance,y.expires
        order by posyear,posmonth

        -- add back in lines that are single credits, w/o debits
                    -- Note: I like this even less! :-\

        INSERT INTO #work3
            (POSYear,POSMonth,TotalDebit,TotalCredit,RollingBalance,EXPYear,EXPMonth)
        select 
            POSYear,
            POSMonth,
            TotalDebit,
            TotalCredit,
            RollingBalance,
        case 
            when expires is null then (POSYear + 1)
        end as EXPYear,
        case 
            when expires is null then 12
        end as EXPMonth
        from #work2
        where (POSYear + POSMonth) NOT IN (
                    select POSYear + POSMonth
                    from #work3);
```

Comment: Why you are creating so many temp table, you can create a one complex query with require join and sub query and same thing can be achieved.

Comment: @Kuldeep, I know right? That's why I'm here asking how! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's the refined version--no temp tables.

```
         SELECT
                POSYear
              , POSMonth
              , TotalDebit AS TotalEarned
              , TotalCredit AS TotalRedeemed
              , RollingBalance
              , EXPYear
              , EXPMonth
              , case 
                  when EXPYear = 2013 then RollingBalance 
                else 0 
                end as EXPRollingBal_2013
              , case 
                  when prevEXPYear <> EXPYear then lag(RollingBalance,1) over (ORDER BY POSYear ,POSMonth) - TotalCredit
                end as "EXPCarryForwardBal"   -- // Note: This only works for the first instance AFTER then new year. Wrong!
              , case 
                  -- when EXPYear = 2014 then RollingBalance  // Note: This is WRONG, zero it out for now.
                  when EXPYear = 2014 then 0.00
                   else 0 
                end as EXPRollingBal_2014
            INTO #baseExpiring
           FROM (
                  SELECT
                      POSYear
                    , POSMonth
                    , TotalDebit
                    , TotalCredit
                    , sum(TotalDebit - TotalCredit) over (ORDER BY POSYear ,POSMonth) AS RollingBalance
                    , EXPYear
                    , EXPMonth
                    , lag(EXPYear,1) over (ORDER BY POSYear ,POSMonth) as prevEXPYear
                   FROM (
                       SELECT
                            year(posdate) AS POSYear
                          , month(posdate) AS POSMonth
                          , sum(debit) AS TotalDebit
                          , sum(credit) AS TotalCredit
                          , CASE 
                              WHEN expires IS NULL THEN year(posdate) + 1 
                                ELSE year(expires) 
                             END AS EXPYear
                          , CASE 
                               WHEN expires IS NULL THEN 12 
                                 ELSE month(expires) 
                            END AS EXPMonth
                          FROM SumTest
                           GROUP BY
                              year(posdate)
                            , month(posdate)
                            , CASE 
                               WHEN expires IS NULL THEN year(posdate) + 1 
                                 ELSE year(expires) 
                               END
                            , CASE WHEN expires IS NULL THEN 12 
                                 ELSE month(expires) 
                              END
                   ) as dataset1  -- // resolve line consolidation when there's a standalone redempton when summed, leaving 2 distinct yyyy,mm rows.
              ) as dataset2  -- // broader resolution of rolling balance w/windowing.
        ;
```

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a need for `#work` which can be replaced with

```
;with distilled as
(
    select POSYear,
            POSMonth,
            TotalDebit = sum(debit),
            TotalCredit = sum(credit),
            expires
    from (
        select datepart(Year, POSDate) as POSYear
                ,datepart(Month, POSDate) as POSMonth
                ,debit
                ,credit
                ,expires
        from sumtest
    )
    group by POSYear,POSMonth,expires
)

select POSYear,
    POSMonth,
    TotalDebit,
    TotalCredit,
    RollingBalance =  sum(totaldebit + (totalcredit)*-1) over ( order by POSYear, POSMonth),
    expires
into #work2
from distilled
```

I think the last two queries can be simplified to

```
select x.POSYear,
        x.POSMonth,
        sum(case when expires is null then 0 else x.TotalDebit end) as TotalDebit,
        sum(case when expires is null then 0 else x.TotalCredit end) as TotalCredit,
        x.RollingBalance,
        EXPYear = case when expires is null then (POSYear + 1)
                        else datepart(Year, y.expires)
                    end,
        EXPMonth = case when expires is null then 12
                         else datepart(Month, y.expires)
                    end
into #work3
from #work2 x
inner join #work2 y on x.posyear = y.posyear
                   and x.posmonth = y.posmonth
group by x.posyear,x.posmonth,x.rollingbalance,y.expires
```

You also don't seem to really need to be `order`ing anything